# Couldn't log out from system in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to logout from the system & I wrote codes below:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['signin', 'logout', 'register', 'index'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index', 'signin', 'register'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
//                'rules' => [
//                    [
//                        'allow' => true,
//                        'actions' => ['logout'],
//                        'roles' => ['@'],
//                    ],
//                    [
//                        'actions' => ['update', 'profile', 'delete', 'all', 'add'],
//                        'allow' => true,
//                        'verbs' => ['GET', 'POST'],
//                        'roles' => ['@'],
//                    ],
//                    [
//                        'actions' => ['signin', 'register'],
//                        'allow' => true,
//                        'roles' => ['?'], // guests
//                        'verbs' => ['GET', 'POST'],
//                    ],
//                    [
//                        'actions' => ['index'],
//                        'allow' => true,
//                        'verbs' => ['GET', 'POST'],
//                        'roles' => ['?'],
//                    ],
//                ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                throw new \Exception('You are not allowed to access this page');
////                    $this->redirect(['daxilol']);
            },
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['POST', 'PUT'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

As you see I've tried too many ways to allow user to get logged out. But in my every attempt it returns:

> ## Exception
>
> You are not allowed to access this page

What's I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try avoiding the only clause at the top

```
   public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
               [
                  'allow' => true,
                  'actions' => ['index', 'signin', 'register'],
                  'roles' => ['?'],
              ],
              [
                  'allow' => true,
                  'actions' => ['logout'],
                  'roles' => ['@'],
              ],
              [
                  'allow' => false,
                  'actions' => ['register'],
                  'roles' => ['@'],
              ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. But when I logged in I can also open the registration page. I think to avoid this I must use `DbManager` or `PhpManager` class. What's your approach sir?

Comment: For the registration page you can place in correct 'rule' .. and witha llow od deny related to this action you can do what do you prefer ... the yii2 ACF is very powerful and is perfectly integrated with rbac i .. use the DB RBAC manager  .. .. i hope my answer and comment are useful for you ..

Comment: I have update also update the answer with  asuggestion for register .

Comment: Thanks. helped a lot.